# Varnish throwing 503 - 'http format error' for a 301 backend response

Tags: http, varnish

I make a request to my backend, lets say for example:

```
curl 'www.epocacosmeticos.com.br/api/vtexid/pub/authentication/oauth/redirect?authenticationToken=dbaf4496-a35f-4393-b2aa-66c633cd91cc&providerName=Google' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: http://www.epocacosmeticos.com.br/login?ReturnUrl=%2faccount%2forders' -H 'Cookie: ISSMB=ScreenMedia%3d0%26UserAcceptMobile%3dFalse; VtexRCMacIdv7=81ee3f61-9b15-11e3-b4b2-9f1bfd993f63; VtexRCRequestCounter=1; VtexRCSessionIdv7=1%253A81ee1850-9b15-11e3-b4b2-9f1bfd993f63; _ga=GA1.3.138072997.1393000243; __utma=226091982.138072997.1393000243.1393000244.1393000244.1; __utmb=226091982.2.9.1393000244; __utmc=226091982; __utmz=226091982.1393000244.1.1.utmcsr%3d(direct)%7cutmccn%3d(direct)%7cutmcmd%3d(none); __bid=82ba78fa-9b15-11e3-855b-0050568438b8-1393000243982-99785454268; __vnr=1; __butms=e69.; __cip=eyJ7bmR%2526%2524m%2526%253B%2524WQi-n%253AiaS!3!nV%253B%2524GVmaW4%2526%2524CJ1fQ..; __pnr=1; __vid=82ba78fa-9b15-11e3-855b-0050568438b8-1393000243982-99785454268; __uor=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.epocacosmeticos.com.br%252F; SGTS=IndiceSegmentoHashCookie%3d1045D4DA0B960F9A25D39084CD6025D6; checkout.vtex.com=__ofid%3d1690a434781a438484df3bb6a15185ce; .ASPXAUTH=85FF63271A0620AB22B47E562CB09392DE69480960F7C4E446BF49E398D71C6D8C07700086D64F79764C020DC9D7DF3157F2940D885A580A107319AF1AC4693EB049F22010F4730A9C383077CF78F35E2E67F8848F7AF30603D68E7460197F92F3AC39A9F56E9F50E7C4DBEC682B44F57AFD11BB23D58FB0028858B4328527D27EC66EA288EFC325195CF865FDC8F77301F066817B185751A2F0E34FF7A6808D03C53EB2688BEA6BDD15EE4DBC41A5D2C0C14E6A9E81130C3DB4400B95F968E952165853; nav22278=9173723934_121; i18next=pt-BR; ISSMB=ScreenMedia=0&UserAcceptMobile=False; nav22278=9173723934_121; .ASPXAUTH=54B8EBA0CEA119D0480D20FB8F08F9BDB895EA7910195E0EB55DFCF1FF94CC1096CC536152930FB06F0CE302BE04159E54BD87E4896D8028C0224E5EBFA9EF28056A32056A7F03D5F374E6FC507D4C9EFA03238D95C763BC6322436857C865B2BF27DC19FE4B63099D1DC2C5A2FBFF04F16D6F2D093340CE3BF7AD3EFAC11589FFD02BDD2D88695BE0D088EFA82EFA8A89DE72AD5376AD8EF05043A5D73F5E8473D60A1230B70ACC5B0FD8A6EF0D50038E1D8C15A450181B720A5F10D17A8CA3438BDC7B; __bid=e2ccd23c-9b1b-11e3-8cca-0050568438b8-1393002980892-20482039195; __vnr=1; SGTS=IndiceSegmentoHashCookie=1045D4DA0B960F9A25D39084CD6025D6; VtexRCSessionIdv7=1%3A4ff8f970-9b2c-11e3-9972-21a9f9abb2ac; VtexRCMacIdv7=e0d1b970-9b1b-11e3-9aa8-21696aee4194; VtexRCRequestCounter=4; _ga=GA1.3.1993338433.1393002979; __utma=226091982.1993338433.1393002979.1393002981.1393010038.2; __utmb=226091982.8.9.1393010047697; __utmc=226091982; __utmz=226091982.1393002981.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __butms=e69.; __pnr=1; __vid=e2ccd23c-9b1b-11e3-8cca-0050568438b8-1393002980892-20482039195; __uor=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.epocacosmeticos.com.br%2Fthat-girl; __cip=eyJ7bmR%26%24m%26%3B%24WQi-n%3AiaS!3!nV%3B%24GVmaW4%26%24CJ1fQ..; checkout.vtex.com=__ofid=7f8daa695f154f8e8e3c4fe7cf132124; i18next=pt-BR' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' --compressed --verbose
```

Then i get this response (along with others 'set-cookie'):

> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Cache-Control: max-age=0
>
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With,
>
> Content-Type, Accept Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Date: Fri, 21 Feb 2014 19:23:17 GMT
>
> Expires: -1
>
> Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=544793639791-flepceudig4p3n1h3m17o8bv9hqn8677.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fvtexid.vtex.com.br%2fVtexIdAuthSiteKnockout%2fReceiveAuthorizationCode.ashx&scope=https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fuserinfo.profile+https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fuserinfo.email&access_type=offline&response_type=code&state=a63c683e-7986-4fd9-a89a-dce70da3e4f9
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Connection: keep-alive

Now i point the DNS to a fresh copy of varnish, defined by a single backend on VCL (the one above). The same request makes varnish throws a 503:

> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Cache-Control: max-age=0
>
> HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
>
> Server: Varnish
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> Retry-After: 5
>
> Content-Length: 419
>
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
>
> Date: Fri, 21 Feb 2014 19:43:11 GMT
>
> X-Varnish: 1045156151
>
> Age: 0
>
> Via: 1.1 varnish
>
> Connection: close

On varnishlog i see this:

> 11 SessionOpen  c 127.0.0.1 59882 :80
>
> 11 ReqStart     c 127.0.0.1 59882 1045156151
>
> 11 RxRequest    c GET
>
> 11 RxURL        c /api/vtexid/pub/authentication/oauth/redirect?authenticationToken=e0f98a75-5f82-41c3-8951-bbc51076ea3f&providerName=Google
>
> 11 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
>
> 11 RxHeader     c Host: www.epocacosmeticos.com.br
>
> 11 RxHeader     c Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>
> 11 RxHeader     c Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>
> 11 RxHeader     c User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
>
> 11 RxHeader     c Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>
> 11 RxHeader     c Referer: http://www.epocacosmeticos.com.br/login?ReturnUrl=%2faccount%2forders
>
> 11 RxHeader     c Cookie: ISSMB=ScreenMedia%3d0%26UserAcceptMobile%3dFalse; VtexRCMacIdv7=81ee3f61-9b15-11e3-b4b2-9f1bfd993f63; 
>   VtexRCRequestCounter=1; VtexRCSessionIdv7=1%253A81ee1850-9b15-11e3-b4b2-9f1bfd993f63; _ga=GA1.3.138072997.1393000243; __utma=226091982.138072997.
>    11 RxHeader     c Connection: keep-alive
>
> 11 RxHeader     c Cache-Control: max-age=0
>
> 11 VCL_call     c recv pass
>
> 11 VCL_call     c hash
>
> 11 Hash         c /api/vtexid/pub/authentication/oauth/redirect?authenticationToken=e0f98a75-5f82-41c3-8951-bbc51076ea3f&providerName=Google
>
> 11 Hash         c www.epocacosmeticos.com.br
>
> 11 VCL_return   c hash
>
> 11 VCL_call     c pass pass
>
> 11 Backend      c 13 prodbackend prodbackend
>
> 11 FetchError   c http format error
>
> 11 VCL_call     c error deliver
>
> 11 VCL_call     c deliver deliver
>
> 11 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
>
> 11 TxStatus     c 503
>
> 11 TxResponse   c Service Unavailable
>
> 11 TxHeader     c Server: Varnish
>
> 11 TxHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> 11 TxHeader     c Retry-After: 5
>
> 11 TxHeader     c Content-Length: 419
>
> 11 TxHeader     c Accept-Ranges: bytes
>
> 11 TxHeader     c Date: Fri, 21 Feb 2014 19:43:11 GMT
>
> 11 TxHeader     c X-Varnish: 1045156151
>
> 11 TxHeader     c Age: 0
>
> 11 TxHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish
>
> 11 TxHeader     c Connection: close
>
> 11 Length       c 419
>
> 11 ReqEnd       c 1045156151 1393011791.083344221 1393011791.505552292 0.000167608 0.422099590 0.000108480
>
> 11 SessionClose c error
>
> 11 StatSess     c 127.0.0.1 59882 0 1 1 0 1 0 257 419

Does anyone have a clue why varnish decided to throw a 503? When fetching from backend, seems like response have a "http format error"... what part of may backend response i have to fix to improve varnish's mood? (tested on 3.0.4 and 3.0.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a config on varnish limiting the number of headers it could receive on backend response: [http_max_hdr](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishd.html)

I've increased this limit to 128 (default is 64) through the param `-p http_max_hdr=128`